# How to find ratio of the groupby column results

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find out the ratio of servers with respect to Environment from the imported excel data.

I have used pandas to import excel

```
Data=pd.read_excel(r"...\Report.xlsx")
```

I have used groupby with respect to Environment("ENV") and Server Names and named the resulting column using reset_index

```
result=Data.groupby(["ENV"])["SRVR_NM"].count().reset_index(name='Server_count')
```

I am getting following result with the above code

```
   ENV                 Server_count
     DR                 1924
     Development         4808
     Integration         687
     Lab                 185
     Production          7619
     QA                 2284
```

Now i want to find ratio of servers with respect to each environment.

For example for first column 1/1924=0.051975,1/4808=0.020799 etc.

How to find ratio of the above result and display the result like

```
       ENV          Server_count     Ratio
      DR             1924             0.051975
      Development    4808             0.020799
      Integration    687                .
      Lab            185                .
      Production     7619               .
      QA             2284               .
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are dividing `1` by the counts, don't you want to divide them by the total sum of the column?

Comment: I want to find ratio proportion with respect to each ENV. For example.. for each column name in ENV with corresponding count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is the reciprocal of the `Server_count` column multipled by 100:

```
result["Ratio"] = (1 / result["Server_count"]) * 100
```

Comment: when i use, result["Ratio"] = (1 / result["Server_count"]) * 100 am getting error as "Keyword can't be expression".   I checked type of result.it shows as dataframe but still it's not working

Comment: Are you missing a closing parenthesis on a function call before this line?

Comment: The code" result["Ratio"] = (1 / result["Server_count"]) * 100 "working properly . but when i try to print it using print(result['ratio']=(1 / result['server_count']) * 100) it shows syntax error "keyword can't be an expression". Also the resulting values should have column name but it doesnt displaying

Comment: Yes, you have to do the assignemnt first (the `result["Ratio"] =` line). If you want to print the result, make a new line after, `print(result["Ratio"])`

Comment: But the resulting values doesn't have column name as Ratio. It simply displays resulting values.How to name the result column. Also could i use .apply method  with lambda to display ratio values  along with 'ENV' and 'SERVER_COUNT'. I tried using .apply but it throws error

Comment: `result["Ratio"] = (1 / result["Server_count"]) * 100` will create a new column called `Ratio`. To print the whole dataframe, just do `print(result)`, or simply type `result` into the interpreter and hit enter.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think your desired output is wrong, it seems that you want the ratio of each `ENV` compared to the total.  For this you can use **`value_counts`** with **`normalize=True`**:

```
options = ['DR', 'Development', 'Integration', 'Lab', 'Production', 'QA']
df = pd.DataFrame([random.choice(options) for _ in range(10000)], columns=['ENV'])
```

Using **`value_counts`**:

```
df.ENV.value_counts(normalize=True)

QA             0.1732
Production     0.1677
Development    0.1677
Lab            0.1644
DR             0.1638
Integration    0.1632
Name: ENV, dtype: float64
```